# clearing IISExpress cache

Tags: asp.net-mvc, powershell, iis, iis-express

I am trying to clear up the IISExpress Cache from the powershell. Using this code it complains about the list.

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\appcmd.exe"  list site /xml | appcmd delete site /in`

How can I clear up the sites and the IIS Express cache?

```
At line:1 char:50
+ "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\appcmd.exe"  list site /xml | app ...
+                                                  ~~~~
Unexpected token 'list' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Easy: Just open `CMD prompt` & Navigate to IIS express - *by typing the following*

> ```
> cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\"
> ```

> ```
> //paste & run this 
> appcmd.exe list site /xml | appcmd delete site /in
> ```

This will delete all the sites, enjoy!

Update for `PowerShell Version` Thanks to @sibbij

> ```
> cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\"
> ```
>
> run this `./appcmd.exe list site /xml | ./appcmd delete site /in`

Comment: Copy paste compatible line for Powershell: `./appcmd.exe list site /xml | ./appcmd delete site /in`

Answer (score 9):

1. Check the **Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location** property(watch, immediatewindow) when you are debugging and you are stopped at some Breakpoint
2. you will see a location like below path

> %temp%\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs...\assembly....\YOUR.dll

3. Check out and delete all folders inside thepath (probably possible after closing IIS express and VS)

> %temp%\Temporary ASP.NET Files\

Comment: Mine wasn't this exact directory, but following your steps I got it. Thank you!

Comment: %temp%\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs will take you to C:\Users\YOURUSERSNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\. You don't have to worry about the username or drive letter.

Comment: For .net core 2, paste this into the immediate window when stopped at a breakpoint in C#: ?System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location

Answer (score 5):

In PowerShell, you need to use the call operator (&) to pass parameters/arguments to an executable.

```
$appCmd = "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\appcmd.exe"

$result = Invoke-Command -Command { & $appCmd 'list' 'sites' '/text:SITE.NAME' }

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $result.length; $i++) {
    Invoke-Command -Command { & $appCmd 'delete' 'site'  $result[$i] }
}
```

Variation from a comment on [this page](https://dotunited.wordpress.com/2013/12/17/delete-all-sites-on-iisexpress-powershell/) :

```
Set-Alias appcmd "$env:ProgramFiles\IIS Express\appcmd.exe"

appcmd list site /text:SITE.NAME | % { appcmd delete site $_ }
```

Comment: Thanks for the post, for me this only gets the first site, not all sites. I have IIS express on Wn10 and while, this previous snippet used to work on wn8.1 its not returning the same result on wn10 for me. Anything I can do to check?

Comment: Do both examples behave the same?

Comment: @sodawillow Please note that the link to "Cleaning up IIS Express Sites" in this post is not working anymore