# IIS Express directory browsing

Tags: iis-express

I know this question has been already asked but it didn't work for me.

When I run the command:

```
appcmd set config /section:system.webServer/directoryBrowse /enabled:true
```

I have the following error:

> The command appcmd was not found, but does exist in the current location. Windows PowerShell does not load commands from the current location by default.

At his point I don't know what to do. How can I run the command?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [clearing IISExpress cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33790405/clearing-iisexpress-cache)

Comment: You need to launch `appcmd.exe` from IIS Express installation folder.

Answer (score 0):

I would try it at the site level first, Run with elevated permission i.e. `Run as Administrator`

**Enable directory browsing at the site level**

> ```
> cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\"
> ```
>
> run this `appcmd.exe set config "Contoso Some SITE NAME" -section:system.webServer/directoryBrowse /enabled:"True" /showFlags:"Date, Time, Size, Extension"`
>   check to turn off encryption and read only in folder options

**Note**: Run with elevated permission

---

GUI version from [Microsoft site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/directorybrowse) for other versions:

1. On the Start screen, move the pointer all the way to the lower left
   corner, right-click the Start button, and then click Control Panel.
2. In Control Panel, click Programs and Features, and then click Turn
   Windows features on or off.
3. Expand Internet Information Services,
   expand World Wide Web Services, expand Common HTTP Features, and
   then select Directory Browsing.

Click OK.
Click Close.

---

If it still does not work, then try & delete all the IIS cache and repeat the above

I previously answered this, [and it works well here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49727908/6085193) for the majority of people

Open CMD prompt & Navigate to IIS express - *by typing the following*

> ```
> cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\"
> ```
>
> run this `appcmd.exe list site /xml | appcmd delete site /in`

This will delete all the sites, enjoy!