# Undo RedirectPermanent in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, iis-express

I made a mistake whilst writing a code in asp.net and used RedirectPermananet incorrectly

```
    public IActionResult index()
    {

        return RedirectPermanent(Url());
    }
```

I have made a change to the value of the url but the browser keeps going to the old url. I've tried clearing the cache using the suggestion shown here [clearing IISExpress cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33790405/clearing-iisexpress-cache), but still having the same problem.
I've realised now that I should not have used RedirectPermanent at the first place. How can I reverse this? Thank you

Comment: Open a browser tab in privacy mode and you shouldn't be redirected by the wrong path. There is no other way to reverse, and clearing browser cache should help (unless you chose the wrong options).

Comment: What browser are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this by clearing the cache of the individual browser ie chrome. Clearing IISExpress cache did not work for me