# How to force database refresh with IIS Express?

Tags: asp.net, mariadb, iis-express

I have an ASP .NET page that calls into a MariaDB database to populate items in a dropdown list.  Yesterday in the morning I was able to make changes in the database and they would show up in the dropdown (either text changes, deletions or insertions, all worked).  Yesterday afternoon my changes no longer showed up, and that continues today.

Environment:

Win10 Enterprise

Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise

MariaDB 10.2.10

I have tried with four different browsers (Chrome, Edge, Firefox & Brave).  [I've cleared caches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33790405/clearing-iisexpress-cache), I've [deleted the IIS Express directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15873126/unable-to-launch-the-iis-express-web-server#17038432) in C:\Users%username%\Documents, I've [changed the port number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21202885/how-can-i-change-iis-express-port-for-a-site) (and seen the change show up in the resultant webpage's address).  [Looked for same port errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12010631/command-line-for-looking-at-specific-port) (this was a problem earlier, but solved now, see above).

Since we run with production & test database instances, I've confirmed that I'm not looking at the production instance, and the edits I've made since yesterday are still in the test instance.  I've also made a minor change to one of the items in the production server and it doesn't show up either (as I'd expect it not to).

I'm running out of ideas and not sure what to try next.

How can I force IIS Express to refresh it's database calls instead of using cached data.

Comment: Have you tried restarting the app and recycling app pool? Have you checked that website is looking at the correct database instance?

Comment: I've restarted the app probably dozens of times, as well as rebooted my machine.  I'm not sure how to recycle the app pool, but I'll Google it, and when we're using the debug instance in VS 2019 it automatically goes to the test instance (and the UI shows "Test Database" in red text so it's hard to mistake.

Comment: If you have rebooted machine with the IIS then no need to recycle app pool. Without access to the environment it is hard to tell anything particular.

Comment: 99% of the time, this happens when the code is not looking at the database instance you think it is. Verify your connection strings.

Comment: @JuanR, while that's possible, and I'll double check, I've made zero changes to the code, the only changes are in the database itself.

Comment: Attach a debugger and watch the flow. Verify the connection, then the query being issued, then the results being returned. You will find your answer then.

Comment: You need to post the markup you have for the drop down list, and you need to post the code behind that loads up the drop down list. Without that information, we can try to re-produce your error. It is doubtful this is a browser issue, or even a browser cache issue here. However, you need to post the code behind that pulls the data and then loads up the drop down list.